# How to select certain id values from a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I select more than one id in one query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1 AND 2 AND 3
```

When I try this I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is because you are using `AND`. It is most likely that no user can have more than one `id`, so you'll need to use `OR` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3;
```

To simplify this even further, you should look into using the `IN` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

**EDIT**

A side note, as I have made this mistake many times, is that you likely approached this because you thought to yourself:

> I want users with ids 1, 2, **AND** 3.

However, the SQL query you're writing says:

> I want users that have id 1, 2, **AND** 3.

But this is not possible. So I recommend you think of it like this:

> I want users whose id values are 1, 2, **OR** 3.

I know that seems like a bit of a tangent, but it is a common misconception that many beginners make, and learning to think about `AND` and `OR` this way will most likely help moving forward.